# Print large pdf page as multiple tiles with small overlap and index marks

Tags: printing, pdf

I have a large document (a pdf with a document size >> A4) that I need to print at 100% scale. This means it will take several A4 sheets.

What I would like is a a small (ideally definable) overlap between pages, plus an index mark in the corners of each sheet so that I can precisely assemble the individual sheets.

Both a GUI application or a command line tool that does the "tiling" would be fine.

Comment: Posterize its in the repos

Comment: @d1bro could you comment on that? I did not find a "posterize" that would do this

Comment: sorry was a shot from the hip and a miss ... see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used a combination of `pdfposter` and `latex` that is described [here](http://leolca.blogspot.com/2010/06/pdfposter.html). Basically, the pdf is first tiled, and the tiles then printed at 1:1 scales on a larger sheet of paper, with crop marks added using the [LaTeX crop package](https://ctan.org/pkg/crop). This works well, especially when automated with a wrapper script.

But maybe there are more out-of-the-box solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a GUI application in the universe repository that is named `posterazor` - it's not a beauty but it works.

Comment: thanks, this is interesting but only works for raster images and has no index marks. In my case these are pdfs with a lot of white space and the marks are needed to register the images.